# C# (mono) not utilizing all cores

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, parallel-processing, mono

We are running a C# project in Mono where we want to utilize multicore CPUs. We are using `System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For` to do so. But we see in `$ top` that Mono only uses 350% of CPU when we are running on a 8 core laptop (which is weird, we expect 700 - 800 %).

We have tried to debug it without any luck but we found something weird. But managed to reproduce the problem with this code snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Cognite.OptimizerMain
{
  public class Triangle
  {
  }

  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Starting parallel work");
      double sum = 0.0;
      Parallel.For(0, 5000, node =>
      {
        for (var k = 0; k < 1000000; k++)
        {
          sum += Math.Abs(Math.Cos(k));
          for (var j = 0; j < 5000; j++)
          {
            // var test_triangle = new Triangle();
          }
        }
      });
      Console.WriteLine(sum);
      Console.WriteLine("Ended parallel work");
    }
  }
}
```

If you run it as it is it utilize 700% - 800% of the CPU. If you uncomment the line with `test_triangle` then we only utilize 350% of the CPU.

We are using this build command: `msbuild Optimizer.sln /p:Configuration=Debug` and running the program like this `mono program.exe`

Can there be any problem with memory allocation / garbage collection?

Comment: Is the program taking significantly longer to run on Linux? Or is CPU usage the only visible impact?

Comment: It also takes longer time to run

Comment: @FredrikAnfinsen What version of Mono are you using as I definitely do not see that when using `Parallel.ForEach`. What exactly does your Parallel.ForEach look like. Also please do not user images for code, paste the formatted code directly into your question (images are not searchable, indexable, readable on different screen sizes, limits accessibly, etc..)

Comment: @SushiHangover I am using `Mono JIT compiler version 5.14.0.177`. The `Parallel.ForEach` function is a system function under `System.Threading.Tasks`.

Comment: @FredrikAnfinsen I understand what Parallel.ForEach is, what I am asking it how have you used it to break your RemoveDegeneratedTriangles method into parallel threads?

Comment: @SushiHangover My misunderstanding. I have updated the code about where you can see how we are using Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: @SushiHangover I have updated the question with a small code snippet to reproduce the problem we had.

Comment: @KevinGosse The question has been updated

Comment: I suspect the JIT is smart enough to remove the useless loop when you remove the `var test_triangle = new Triangle();` line, thus making the iteration complete faster. I'm not sure that's enough to explain the difference in CPU usage though

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever profile a debug build, because in a debug build is a lot of code which is removed in a release build and that gives you another behavior than a release build does.

Your creation of new Triangle is basically useless because it will be removed in a release build, because there's no result which will be used.

I've no mono so I tried to reproduce your described behavior on a windows machine (.NET Core 2.1). I could see your described behavior too with a debug build.
With a release build i get nearly 94% cpu usage and with a debug build nearly 56% with the 
line

```
var test_triangle = new Triangle();
```

I expect this happens because in a debug build the line

```
var test_triangle = new Triangle();
```

is executed. While in a release build it's optimized away, which could lead to optimize the whole for loop away, than the compiler can optimize the second for loop and so on, which will not be done in a debug build. The generated IL code has to be checked to verify this, I'm too lazy to do it now. :)

So first you should profile a release build and second to get a better test you should do something inside the inner loop which you will use at the end of the programm. To do so the optimizer can't remove the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This was just a small example to reproduce the problem we have for a bigger project. We are building for release on the big project which gives the same bad utilization of cores as for a debug build.